# How can i use orbot in my college??its not working

Tags: orbot

i have a tor application called orbot and it does not function well in our college..how do i configure orbot so i can access tor serviceses in our college networks??
My college has a server based on isa server..it has a proxy@172.20.0.2 and port@8080....
so can anyone tell me specifically how to configure orbot..oh and my college blocks most websites including facebook,twiiter,and watsapp and anything like that...sorry for the bad english...so please help 
This is the log

---

```
Orbot is starting…
Orbot is starting…
updating settings in Tor service
updating torrc custom configuration...
success.
Orbot is starting…
Tor (1): Mar 18 20:48:26.600 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1q and Zlib 1.2.8.
Mar 18 20:48:26.601 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Mar 18 20:48:26.601 [notice] Read configuration file "/data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/torrc".
Mar 18 20:48:26.601 [notice] Read configuration file "/data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/torrc.custom".
Mar 18 20:48:26.624 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:0
Mar 18 20:48:26.625 [notice] Socks listener listening on port 33324.
Mar 18 20:48:26.625 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
Mar 18 20:48:26.626 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
Mar 18 20:48:26.626 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9040: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Mar 18 20:48:26.626 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:0
Mar 18 20:48:26.626 [notice] Control listener listening on port 60999.
Mar 18 20:48:26.626 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:33324
Mar 18 20:48:26.627 [notice] Closing partially-constructed DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
Mar 18 20:48:26.627 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:60999
Mar 18 20:48:26.627 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Mar 18 20:48:26.627 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Answer (score -1):

You need **Meek** and **obfs4** pluggable transports and bridges. Also a good point will be to rise your own Tor bridge, where you won't be publishing it's descriptor and using it too in your "mobile" access. Once properly seeded and bridged - Orbot can penetrate such censorship

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that Orbot could not bind to port 9040 because it's already in use. We just need to find out what's using that port.

Comment: @SuperSluether maybe, but it can appear also if an Orbot lags on connect with no port interference, I saw it myself on a censored network - it used to conflict with itself.